# how do I draw samples from correlated uniform random variables given a correlation matrix

Tags: distributions, correlation, monte-carlo, random-generation, uniform-distribution

For a simulation study I am trying to generate samples from 4 correlated random variables following a multivariate uniform distribution, where all marginals are uniform variables and the population correlation coefficients are given by the following correlation matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 1.00 0.55 0.65 0.75    
[2,] 0.55 1.00 0.70 0.80
[3,] 0.65 0.70 1.00 0.85
[4,] 0.75 0.80 0.85 1.00
```

Sample correlation may of course vary according to whatever $Var(\rho)$ is in this case. I am pretty new to simulation and Monte Carlo. My research concerning copulas has only lead me to inverse-transformation solutions starting from correlated normals so far, where the pearson-correlation changes with the transformation to uniform.

The closest I have come is the approximate solution from here, which is probably good enough for what I want to achieve: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/322861/197690.

I am also reading Kalos/Whitlock's "Monte Carlo Methods", and they write the following:

> where X and Y are correlated, it is useful to write the joint pdf as
>   $$
> f(x,y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy=f(y\mid x)m(x)
> $$
>   with
>   $$
> f(y\mid x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy}
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> m(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy
> $$
>   That is, when the marginal and conditional functions can be determined, sampling a bivariate distribution requires simply sampling two univariate distributions.

This made me wonder if I can somehow determine the conditional functions I need, at least in the bivariate case. The marginals are easy, as $m(x)=1$ in the standard uniform case.

But I am stuck at trying to specify $ f_{x\mid y}(x\mid y) $ or $f_{x,y}(x,y)$ in a way that returns the correlation I want. Is any of this even possible?

Keep in mind that I have little theoretical understanding of copulas - if copulas are what I need and you know of any good resources, I'd be greatful if you can direct me to them. I will be doing the simulation with R, by the way. Thanks for any help!

Comment: A critical part of the description of any uniform distribution is its *support*. Somehow you need to provide information that lets us deduce the full multivariate distribution; correlations alone do not suffice--as the theory of copulas makes clear.  Thus, the short answer to your question "is this even possible" is no, unless you can provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Why do you need a support? If the only requirement I have on the distribution is the correlation, shouldn't my choice of supports be arbitrary? In my understanding, neither additive nor multiplicative scaling of the supports affects the correlations. Anyway, looks like I'll spend tomorrow looking for resources on copulae. None of the books I have on simulation have chapters on copulas, and I'm unable to understand the wikipedia page.

Comment: You refer explicitly to a "multivariate uniform distribution."  A uniform distribution is *defined* by its support. For instance, there's little you could say about the univariate uniform distribution I presently have in mind.  Does it assign any probability to positive numbers?  You cannot possibly know. Likewise, we cannot possibly know what you are asking about unless you provide more information.

Comment: @whuber Does it help if I define the support as continuous over [a,b]^n (with an n-dimensional correlation matrix Sigma)? In my understanding, once I successfully draw samples from that distribution, I could easily rescale the marginal uniform distributions to fit any U(a,b) I need, without messing up the correlations.

If the above doesn't help, does it maybe help to assume the support is [0,1]^2 and rho=0.5? I would call this one a correlated bivariate continuous standard uniform distribution. I'm sorry if I'm being dense.

Comment: You're not dense at all.  I think everything you write is correct.  I may just have a more general understanding of what a uniform distribution is.  To me, it's any distribution supported on a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that inherits the (normalized) Lebesgue measure.  That would include, for instance, the uniform distribution on the unit ball $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n\mid ||x||^2 \le 1\},$ even though that set is not of the form $[a,b]^n.$ I have supposed the correlations are induced by the *shape* of the support of your distribution. Otherwise, the correlations must all be zero.

Comment: Here's a concrete example: consider the uniform distribution on the union of squares $[0,1]^2\cup[1,2]^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2.$ The marginals are uniform on $[0,2]$ and the correlation is positive.  *That's* the sort of thing your question seems to be asking about.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared up a couple of things that were kind of fuzzy in my head. You were right about me having a more narrow understanding of uniform distributions than you, and you also helped me understand a bit more about what copulas actually do. I will look into it some more tomorrow and come back to this question once I have a clearer understanding.